# Build and Emulate Android Apps in Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

After setting all configuration, the log:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\John\Desktop\COMCOM~1.MER\build.xml

BUILD FAILED

C:\Users\John\Desktop\COMCOM~1.MER\build.xml:37: The following error occurred    while    executing this line:

C:\android-sdk-windows_r14\tools\ant\pre_setup.xml:4: Your build.xml file is outdated. Delete it and regenerate it with 'android update project'



Total time: 0 seconds

OPERATION CANCELED
```

What does this mean??
It really load the emulator but nothing appears in it

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
X:\Android\android-sdk\tools>android update project -p “your project's full path”
```

Answer (score 0):

Google updated the format of the build.xml project in version 14 of the SDK, released around October, 2011. You can run  `android update project` from your `C:\Users\John\Desktop\COMCOM~1.MER\` directory and that should fix the problem.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: You have to run it from the command line, which in Windows is the MS-DOS prompt.

Comment: not work=.=  Error: The parameter --path must be defined for action 'update project'

Comment: make sure you're in the root of your project when running the following command: 
android update project -p .